# How do I disable the onclick of parent when live child is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, live

So typically I just use stopPropegation when I need to prevent the default action of the parent when a child is clicked. However, this doesn't seem to be work with live elements. So I had the idea to temporarily remove the onclick attribute of the parent when the child is hovered over. I seem to be able to remove it just fine, but I cannot seem to be add it back to the element... this is what I came up with...

```
$('body').delegate('.button', 'mouseenter mouseout', function(e){
        if(e.type=='mouseenter'){
          var inside = $(this).parents('.post').attr('onclick');
          $(this).parents('.post').attr('onclick','');
        }else if(e.type=='mouseout'){
          $(this).parents('.post').attr('onclick', inside);
        }
    })
```

So this will remove the element successfully, however the attempt to add it back is always unsuccessful... it just comes up empty. Can anyone give me a hand here? I'm completely stuck. I'd also be happy with alternative method to achieving the same result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/kDuNU/4/:

```
$('div').live('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('button'))
       return;
    alert('hello');
});

$('.a-span').live('click', function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
$('div').append('<span class="a-span button">another</span>');

<div> hello <br/>
    <span class="a-span">world</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @itdoell "I need to prevent the default action of the parent when a child is clicked" My code works as you expected. But you need to rewrite it to your own code.

Comment: That's not what I said... I said on a live element... That is not a live element...

Comment: Okay, I take that back, your solution does work except that I don't want to block it for all children, I only want to block it for .button child. So this solution doesn't seem practical for my situation. Thank you though

Comment: @itdoell Try this new version, it checks the .button class

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(e.type=='mouseenter'){
    $(this).parents('.post').unbind('click');
}else if(e.type=='mouseout'){
    $(this).parents('.post').bind('click');
}

//OR place your inside variable before if, like
var inside = $(this).parents('.post').attr('onclick');  //placed outside of if
if(e.type=='mouseenter'){   
   $(this).parents('.post').attr('onclick','');
}else if(e.type=='mouseout'){
   $(this).parents('.post').attr('onclick', inside);
}
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: edited, try placing your "inside" variable outside of if statement.

Comment: Still doesn't work, the onclick element becomes this... <div class="post" id="postIiZ2Zt" onclick="">